# Pull request (Merge request) в stage и main

Tags: git, main

Вопрос - вот у меня к примеру есть 2 ветки stage и main, при push в stage запускается CI\CD и изменения улетают на stage версию сайта, а при push в main на боевой. Куда разработчикам нужно делать свой pull request? Сначала на stage а потом оттуда я уже, после approve и тестов, через cherry-pick скопирую этот merge commit в ветку main ? Как правильно делать?

Comment: "Правильно" - всё-таки понятие субъективное......Но, конечно, лучше, когда к main ветке доступ имеет конкретное ответственное лицо, а не все подряд.

Comment: все коммитят в stage, а как сборка стабилизирована, делается коммит из stage в main. А еще лучше добавить промежуточную ветку, что бы отделить разработку от тестирования

Comment: @SwaD "делается коммит из stage в main" каким образом, merge (что вроде как не очень хорошо) или через cherry-pick все таки? И что нужно копировать, коммит pull reques`та или все те коммиты которые пришли в этом pull reques`е? И можете плз. объяснить для чего нужна еще одна промежуточная ветка, для чего ее использовать и как?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у меня так и сделано, вопрос в том как в main переносить эти коммиты которые я аппрувлю. Их нужно копировать из той ветки куда pull request пришел (stage), или напрямую копировать из ветки разработчика (после того как выяснилось что stage не упал, т.е после approve pull request`а).

Comment: У всех разные возможности по выделению стендов. У меня есть стенд разработки(одна ветка), стенд предтестирования, куда сливаем более менее стабильный код(все из дева льем одним коммитом), тестим сами сборку, далее коммитим в ветку тестирования, далее в ветку предпрода, там смотрят, как ведет себя сборка на почти промышленных данных, затем коммит в main(master) для выкатывания релиза на промышленный стенд. Как организовывать передачу коммитов от одной ветки к другой - пусть решает ваша команда

Comment: @SwaD - "ваша команда" это один я)) Я в роли и разработчика (ведущего) и в роли DevOps. По поводу дополнительных веток и этапов понял, но вот именно как правильнее коммиты переносить так и не понял. С stage на main копировать аппрувнутый коммит, или независимо копировать этот коммит (коммиты) с ветки разработчиков? Или просить их после тестов на stage (если они прошли успешно) что бы они сделали pull request еще и в main ?

Comment: По-хорошему, не должно быть никаких изменений кода (а любой merge или cherry-pick это изменение) между разными средами. Иначе получается тестировали одну версию, а на проде будем деплоить другую. В вашем случае stage означает "версия-кандидат, еще не протесированна". Нужно ввести еще одни бранч stable. После успешных тестов на stage, stable перенаправляется на версию, которая прошла тестированние. Это "протестированная и готовая к релизу версия". Для деплоя на прод main перенаправляется (без никаких merge и cherry-pick) на stable. В итоге это точно та же версия, что тестировали на stage

Comment: Разработчики PR-ы создают на ветку stage в такой схеме (для надежности от ветки stable). stage будет обычно чуть впереди stable (и совпадать если нет новых не протестированных изменений), а stable чуть впереди main (совпадает, если все протестированное уже залито на прод). Необязательно это делать ветками. По сути здесь ветка одна, но дополнительно мы храним номера версий "протестированная" (stable) и "задеплоенная на прод" (main). Можно хранить это где-то отдельно, но ветками это делать удобней.

Comment: @Roman все логично, да, только я не понял а как это "main перенаправляется (без никаких merge и cherry-pick) на stable" ? У меня это сайт, и есть три его копии, боевая main (site.ru), стейдж (stage.site.ru) и dev (dev.site.ru). Как я могу там перенаправлять что то? У меня CI\CD выгружает код из разных веток в разные директории сайтов на боевом сервере,  вот и все.

Comment: Когда я говорю перенаправляется, я имею ввиду указатель ветки в репозитории git. Команда типа `git branch -f main stable`. Где-то кто-то сейчас у вас делает или собирается делать merge из stable в main или что-то, чтоб изменения из stable попали в main. Вот вместо этого нужно просто передвинуть указатель ветки. Ну и потом уже делать push этого изменения указателя на remote репозиторий, если у вас по push запускается CI.